# How do a really clear cache in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, caching

I would like to run the same query multiple times to see how much time it takes without the aid of cache memory.
Running the command RESET QUERY CACHE seems not to work because the query takes a really short time on the second run even after the cache reset.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SQL_NO_CACHE` in the `SELECT` query.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-in-select.html

Keep it in mind that Query cache has been removed in later versions of MySQL.

Depending on the storage engine, (e.g innodb), it loads table data into memory as part the buffer pool. This part you can't really control on what tables to load and which tables not to load (or at least not easily).

Comment: just adding SQL_NO_CACHE to my select actually does not work. query will be always faster on the 2nd run

Comment: This is due to the fact some of the data, not the exact query result, would be cached in the innodb buffer pool. So when next time the query is executed, MySQL is scanning the data from the memory only. This will be magnitudes levels of faster compared to normal disk read. Hence you will see the faster query execution time in the second run. If you want to get more details on query execution then try to profile the query. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-examples.html

Answer (score 3):

Your OS is caching a whole lot of data. Then the DBMS itself caches a whole of data. The query cache only holds the output of a previous query. The data the query output is created from may all be in RAM. If you want to run the query without any caching then switch off the host between executions or run a query which will read enough data from disk to overwrite all the cache. But it won't be a realistic measure of ho.w your query will perform in the wild.

Answer (score 3):

Two "caches" affects the query. `Query Cache` and `Buffer Cache(buffer_pool with InnoDB and key_buffer with MyISAM)`. `Query cache` affects much more than `Buffer Cache` because it caches the result of your query, so the same query will not execute again.

To avoid `Query Cache`, uses `SQL_NO_CACHE` is a good idea, and you can disable `Query Cache` in `my.cnf` and restart mysql.

`Buffer cache` is managed by mysql to cache data in memory so that your query will not read data from disk(SSD or HDD). If you want to clear it, try to set the 'Buffer cache' small enough and fill it with other data(use `SELECT`).

Answer (score 0):

On an ancient version of MySQL (v.5.1), I had a problem with a view being cached, which would never refresh.  I tried `RESET QUERY CACHE` , `FLUSH TABLES`, `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE...`, etc. And nothing worked.  Then, I changed the storage engine for the underlying (single) table I was querying in this view, from **InnoDB** to **MyISAM**, and it worked as desired implicitly!  There was no need to jump through any hoops to clear or prevent caching!

I'm not sure if this was simply a bug with that old version / storage engine?  Please leave comments if you have any knowledge to share on the matter.

Comment: it's obv because the "cache" data were stored in the innodb buffer

Comment: And none of the things I tried to clear the cache/buffer can ever work with innodb by definition?

Comment: correct. 
I think you can only reset the innodb buffer my restarting the server or mysqld

Comment: Well, I would hope that one could at least close and reopen a connection / session to resolve this?  If a view could never be refreshed without recycling the entire db service it would be pretty useless more often than not.

Comment: that's the way it is my friend :D